# Facing issue in DD4T 2.0.8 with WEB 8

Tags: dd4t, web8

I am working on **DD4T 2.0.8** version and **WEB 8** . i have installed the **DD4T.Templates.2.0.8** and using **DD4T.Providers.SDLWeb8** .

the issue which  i am facing is when hitting **base.Page(pageId)** its throwing an error the inner exception is shows that the method name **GetContentByUrl(string Url)** returning the empty string[]  **string[] resultUris = pageQuery.ExecuteQuery();** although the default page exist in the broker 
'

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration Version="8.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd"> <Global>
    <Storages>
        <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL"
                 Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120"/>
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="localhost" />
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
                <Property Name="user" Value="*****" />
                <Property Name="password" Value="****" />
            </DataSource>
        </Storage> 
    </Storages><Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile"
                 defaultFilesystem="false">
            <Root Path="C:\visitorsweb" />
        </Storage>
        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile"
                 defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">
            <Root Path="C:\visitorsweb\data" />
        </Storage>


    </Storages>
</Global>

<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">

    <Publication Id="8" defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false"> 
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Jsp" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Asp" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Xml" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Txt" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Metadata" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".pdf" storageId="defaultdb" cached="true"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".iso" storageId="defaultdb" cached="false"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentLinkClick" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentVisit" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="DynamicLinkInfo" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Personalization" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Taxonomy" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Timeframe" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="TrackedPage" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="XSLT" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ExtensionData" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/> 
    </Publication> 
</ItemTypes>

<License Location="C:\WEB8Licence\cd_licenses.xml"/>

<ConfigRepository ServiceUri="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc"
                  ConnectionTimeout="40000"
                  CacheEnabled="true"
                  CacheExpirationDuration="600"
                  ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10"
                  ClientId="registration"
                  ClientSecret="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY=">
    <Roles>
        <Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://localhost:8084/httpupload">
            <Property Name="undo.enabled" Value="false"/>
            <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
        </Role>
    </Roles>
</ConfigRepository>
```

'
Criteria of the broker query is also correct i don't see any issue

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: while trying to debug the issue we found that we are not getting any request in the SQL profiler

Comment: Are you using cd api as in-process setup or REST ? And have you defined publication Mappings using Topology manager or cd_dynamic_conf.xml ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that you should check:

1. cd_storage_conf.xml is pointing to correct broker database. If there
   is mismatch then there are chances that you will not see the page.
2. Check web.config of the application to make sure that you don't have
       DD4T.CacheSettings.Page set to a big value.

Either of the above case will give the behavior that you are noticing.

Comment: i have checked my broker setting and it is pointing to correct broker DB as my published data is going to broker .
and as far as web.config setting is concerned , i  dont have DD4T.CacheSettings.Page  setting . is it compulsory to have this setting key

Comment: What I meant was storage config of your web application. I understand your publishing is working fine that's how you are seeing the content.

Comment: yes my web application storage config is also have the same broker DB details .

Comment: Then only possibility that I can think of is with dd4t caching. Also, can you post you storage config here?

Comment: I have updated my question with site storage config file